# PHP Adding Slashes to Form Submitted File Path

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that contains a field for a desktop file path. The path is saved then written to a txt file and then read from that file and the value is put in the form field.

When submitted, slashes are added. In fact whatever slashes are in the path are doubled each time the form is submitted.

Any thoughts around this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have magic quotes enabled. To check if they're enabled, place the following in your script:

```
echo 'magic_quotes_gpc=', ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc');
echo 'magic_quotes_runtime=', ini_get('magic_quotes_runtime');
```

If either of them return `1`, then you should disable them. You can also check for this information by running the function `phpinfo();` in your script.

Refer to the manual for the best methods of disabling them:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: I've decided to scrap the form field where you enter the path and just hardcode it. But, "C:\Users\Files\" causes an error and "C:\Users\Files" outputs without the slashes even though I don't have stripslashes in my code.

Comment: You get the error because the last slash is escaping the quote. Check out the [manual page on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your server must have [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.  You can use `stripslashes()` to get rid of them, but it's possible it will remove all slashes rather than just the ones which were added.